# How to generate weekly and monthly automated report using sas macro?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

How to generate a automated code for which it should generate a weekly report from Monday to Saturday only.
It should take Monday as 1st value and Saturday as 2nd value.
Except Monday n Saturday it should not detect any other day of the week...

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple steps that need to take place before you can create automated tasks.
Without any information I can't be of more help then describe the general procedure I use.

1. Create a %let that allows you to use "SYSDAY" to be equal to Monday/Thursday/etc.

   %macro days;
   %global yourweekday;
   %if %sysday=Monday %then %do; %let yourweekday=1; end;
   %if %sysday=Tuesday %then %do; %let yourweekday=2; end;
   %if %sysday=Wednesday %then %do; %let yourweekday=3; end;
   %mend yourweekday;
   %weekday;
2. Create your code and incorporate the macro and what every report should say, like "%Sysday" report for ........
3. Add an email trigger to your code that sends the report you want to the specified email address/upload to FTP site or place it the right folder
4. Create a batch file with the file path of sas, your program, a -print .lst and a -log .log
5. For windows, schedule this batch file to run on the days and time you want it to run.

Again, if you give some more details I could answer the question better